# python simple substitute variableㄴ (opencv image processing)

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0E4s.png)

Why img is same result with img_gray?

I think img must be showed original image.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Do *not* post your code as an image.

Comment: you have to duplicate image - `img_gray = img.copy()` - without `copy()` both variables keeps access to the same image in memory. It is standard behavior in Python.

Comment: Can i ask why do not post image? Does it have error?

Comment: @BBoDDo "*Can i ask why do not post image?*" People here volunteer their time to help others. You should then make it easier for others by posting your code as text, so that potential helpers can copy-paste them to their own editors and help you solve your problem. We cannot run images of code. Other reasons explained here: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2745495).

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer. For now on, i will write code directly.

Comment: @BBoDDo As another tip, if an answer solved your problem, consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. This will clearly indicate to others reading this Q&A that that specific answer is the solution. And, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to duplicate image

```
img_gray = img.copy()
```

Without `copy()` both variables gives access to the same image in memory.

It is standard behavior in Python.

Comment: Oh! Thak you so much!
I started python today :)